# wpf application showing error on client PC while start

Tags: wpf

I develop one WPF application .It works on my machine .But while runnning on client machine it showing this error

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3

Problem Signature 01: Project.exe

Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0

Problem Signature 03: 55f94c7e

Problem Signature 04: PresentationFramework

Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.34209

Problem Signature 06: 5348b261

Problem Signature 07: 98f

Problem Signature 08: 0

Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileLoadException

OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48

Locale ID:    1033

Additional Information 1: 0a9e

Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Additional Information 3: 0a9e

Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

.Net Framework 4 and 4.5 is there on client machine

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an application crash error.

The big thing here is that somewhere in your program threw a FileLoadExcepetion.

Explanation from MSDN:

> The exception that is thrown when a managed assembly is found but cannot be loaded.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileloadexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Follow the solution in the article below and find the method which throw this exception in your application and then fix it.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oanapl/archive/2009/01/30/windows-error-reporting-wer-and-clr-integration.aspx

Hopefully this gives you enough context to fix your issue.

Comment: But on other client machine it works fine .But today I found this on one machine after installing.So is it possible that my application threw a FileLoadException